# Passing Constant Value from ConfigProperty in Quarkus

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I need to pass a prefix in front of my kafka topics because we use the same kafka for all enviroments. In SpringBoot it's quite simple, something like:

> local_foor_bar
>
> hmlg_foo_bar
>
> prod_foo_bar

In spring it works just fine like this:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${spring.env_prefix}foo_bar")
```

But I'm trying to do the same in quarkus using smallrye but it's not working because it states that it needs to be a constant value:

My properties:

```
%dev.env_prefix=local_
%homolog.env_prefix=hmlg_
%prod.env_prefix=prod_
```

Kafka consumer example:

```
    private static final String generateChargeBillet = ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("env_prefix", String.class) + "foo_bar";

    @Incoming(generateChargeBillet)
    public void process(String createBilletRequest) {
    ...
    }
```

I've tried also:

```
@Incoming("${envPrefix}foo_bar")
public void process(String createBilletRequest) {

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting when using `${envPrefix}foo_bar`?